# Center except when an overlap would occur

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to accomplish a toolbar layout that includes 3 components.  The left and center are flexible in size to the point where I don't think standard responsive breakpoints will do the job.  The flexible center should be centered relative to the viewport when space allows.  However, if the center and left would be overlapping, the center section is permitted to become off-center in order to avoid having to hide content.

Toolbar with wide viewport:

[image: Toolbar with wide viewport]

Toolbar with narrow viewport.  Note the Section Title is not perfectly centered.  This is desireable because it would overlap the breadcrumb:

[image: Toolbar with narrow viewport]

I thought maybe flexbox could do this, but I'm struggling to make it work.  Below is an attempt I have made to do this using flexbox.

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar">
  <div>Site / Section A / Section A1 / Section A1b</div>
  <div class="section-title">This Section Title</div>
  <div>Site Search</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.toolbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.section-title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/YoD0yLWliXhu191jUrv4?p=preview

Comment: It's hard to understand... why is Section title off center ?

Comment: That is indeed the problem with my punker.  I'd like the Section Title to appear like they do in the mockup images above.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

As you're using flexbox, you can use justify-content declaration instead of text-align.

Like this:

```
.section-title {
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

There's a great article about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: I know you've said you don't think breakpoints will do the job. But I think a media query could actually help to center the title on larger widths. This way you'll be free to style it on mobile first.

Comment: This isn't quite what was asked for. This centers the middle elements between the two outer elements, NOT the window itself.